# BIOS and Windows show different amounts of RAM

Tags: dell-poweredge

I upgraded my server, a Dell Power-edge 2900, from 2 GB (4 sticks of 512 MB) to 10 GB (by adding 2 sticks of 4 GB). On the BIOS it shows the correct size of my ram but on Windows Server 2003 it shows only 4 GB ram size. Can it be fixed?

Comment: Which version of windows server are you using? Datacentre, enterprise or standard?  (  [Windows Server 2003](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_server_2003_r2)  **standard edition** supports a maximum of 4 GiB on X86. )

Comment: @suraphel - The version of WIndows Server 2003 you are using doesn't support more than 4GB.

Answer (score 1):

You must have Windows Server 2003 Standard 32-bit, which only supports 4gb RAM. You'll have to switch to 64-bit version (supports upto 32gb) or upgrade to Enterprise edition (supports upto 64gb).